# Sandbox session gets confused across browser tabs

Tags: sandbox, session

I have noticed that if I login to a `test.salesforce.com` sandbox in one Safari tab, and a different `test.salesforce.com` sandbox in a second tab, that the login sessions can become confused. One tab will switch over to use the other org's session. I understand that it is normal for tabs to share the same session information but this presents a difficulty when trying to work reliably with two sandboxes at once. What is the best solution?

Comment: Use different browsers (e.g. chrome & firefox).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an incognito window or a different browser. You should only experience this issue if both orgs are on the same instance, e.g. `cs12`.

Comment: Yes, I get around this by using Chrome, Firefox and Edge (as I'm on Windows) also it is good for testing cross browser compatibility too with the UI.

Comment: I prefer My Domain to the browser juggling solution, but this solution certainly works.

Comment: The votes can decide, but a solution that requires a refresh certainly carries more overhead and risk.

Comment: Also custom domains complicate usage of several other tools.

Answer (score 5):

Set up [My Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_overview.htm&type=0) in your production org, then refresh your sandboxes. They'll each get unique domains, and will allow you to work seamlessly in multiple orgs. The URL for each sandbox will change to something like "https://*mydomainname*--*sandboxname*.*instance*.my.salesforce.com/". This lets you open *many* sandboxes with virtually zero risk of sessions getting clobbered.

Answer (score 2):

I use a Chrome extension called Multi-Login. It allows you to open a new tab with separate session data. It works for SF, social media sites, whatever you want. If I open a link from that session into a new tab, then it's within the same session. If I click the button from the extension, I can generate myself another session.

So, I can have as many SF orgs as I want open in separate tabs.

For some reason it was pulled from the Chrome store, but this guy has a backup of the package here:

http://www.theyanglu.com/toolkit/multiple-sessions-in-google-chrome-with-multilogin

I've never used it, but there is a tool to do the same thing which is still available on the Chrome store here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-free-multi-log/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig?hl=en